# How to update state when props changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I have a component Parent, which render a big form.
Parent-component has presentational child components Child1 - Child4, which render inputs.

When Parent.props are changing, values of Child1 - Child4 should be dropped to default from props.
A user has to have an ability to change ChildN value by parent method.

I need something like componentWillReceiveProps,
to calculate new Parent.state depending on Parent.props when it changes only.

I can't use getDerivedStateFromProps, because I need access to old props and new either.
getDerivedStateFromProps give access to new props only.
I don't want to use componentWillReceiveProps.

```
class Parent extends Component {
state = {
    value: Object.assign({}, this.props.value)
};
handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        value: event.currentTarget.value
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <Child
            onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.value}/>

    )
}}class Child extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <input type="text"
           name="input"
           value={this.props.value}
           onChange={this.props.onChange.bind(this)}
        />

    )
}}
```

Comment: Suggest you to go thru this https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions

Comment: you could use shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: whenever some props change the component updates, and you can easily use `prevProps` and `prevState` there look at https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html

Comment: @VarunTheFalcon `shouldComponentUpdate` is for a different purpose altogether

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
if (this.props.value.id !== nextProps.value.id) {
    this.setState({
        value: Object.assign({}, nextProps.value)
    });
}
return true;}
```

Minus: component re-render twice if props changed.
Another option:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
if (this.props.value.id !== nextProps.value.id) {
    this.state.value: Object.assign({}, nextProps.value)
}
return true;}
```

Minus: direct mutation, but render() already called.
I don't like both options(and using componentDidUpdate), they don't look like best practice.

Comment: It breaks "Single Responsibility Principle" of a function. It should just do a boolean check but it is doing other stuff as well. What about componentDidUpdate(..) ?